# Consider defining a bean of type 'mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.repositories.SessionRepository' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-repositories

I am currently trying out a Spring boot application with Redis.I have a problem related to spring boot concerning redis repositories when I try to execute the program.

**When I run the app I get the following error:**

```
2017-09-02 09:21:37.065  INFO 5130 --- [st-startStop-18] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-09-02 09:21:37.106  WARN 5130 --- [st-startStop-18] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSessionService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionServiceImpl' defined in file [/rezsystem/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/sessionmanager/WEB-INF/classes/rezg/rezos/sessionmanager/services/SessionServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.repositories.SessionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2017-09-02 09:21:37.118  INFO 5130 --- [st-startStop-18] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-09-02 09:21:37.306 ERROR 5130 --- [st-startStop-18] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

**Description:**
Parameter 0 of constructor in mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.services.SessionServiceImpl required a bean of type 'mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.repositories.SessionRepository' that could not be found.

**Action:**
Consider defining a bean of type 'mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.repositories.SessionRepository' in your configuration.
```

The related source files are listed below

**Service Interface**

```
package mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.services;

import java.util.List;

public interface SessionService {

    List<String> listAll();

    String getById(String Key);
}
```

**Service Implemention**

```
package mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.repositories.SessionRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Service
public class SessionServiceImpl implements SessionService{

    private SessionRepository sessionRepository; //error refere to this 

    @Autowired
    public SessionServiceImpl(SessionRepository sessionRepository) {
        this.sessionRepository = sessionRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> listAll() {
        List<String> allSessions = new ArrayList<>();
        sessionRepository.findAll().forEach(allSessions::add);
        return allSessions;
    }

    @Override
    public String getById(String Key) {
        return sessionRepository.findOne(Key);
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
package mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface SessionRepository extends CrudRepository<String, String> {

}
```

**Controller**

```
package mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.services.SessionService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/sessionmanager")
public class SessionController {

     final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionController.class);

     private SessionService sessionService;

         @Autowired
     public void setSessionService(SessionService sessionService) {
        this.sessionService = sessionService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/servicecheck", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String servicecheck() {
        return "This is the First Message From Remote session manager service!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String listAllSessions(Model model){
               model.addAttribute("sessions", sessionService.listAll());
               return "display all Sessions";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/session/show/{key}")
        public String getProduct(@PathVariable String key, Model model){
               model.addAttribute("product", sessionService.getById(key));
               return "display selected Sessions";
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
package mezg.mezos.sessionmanager;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("mezg.mezos.sessionmanager")
public class SessionStoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SessionStoreApplication.class, args);
    }
```

**Gradle Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

There were similar scenarios described on this forum and I did try out the suggested solutions but could resolve this issue.Some of these issue are listed below.

Stack overflow Reference

[Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ensat.services.ProductService' in your configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451227/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-com-ensat-services-productservice-in-your-con?rq=1)

[Consider defining a bean of type 'package' in your configuration [Spring-Boot]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384056/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-package-in-your-configuration-spring-boot?rq=1)

[Consider defining a bean of type 'service' in your configuration [Spring boot]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663652/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-service-in-your-configuration-spring-boot)

[Spring boot CrudRepo Define a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048817/spring-boot-crudrepo-define-a-bean)

[Spring boot + redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705726/spring-boot-redis)

**Other References**

http://www.cnblogs.com/exmyth/p/7119225.html

------------------------**UPDATE 1**-----------------------

Tried Updating the Main Class with **@ComponentScan** and **@EnableRedisRepositories**

```
package mezg.mezos.sessionmanager;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"mezg.mezos.sessionmanager","mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.controller","mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.services","mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.repositories"})
@EnableRedisRepositories("mezg.mezos.sessionmanager.repositories")
public class SessionStoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SessionStoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

------------------------**UPDATE 2**-----------------------

**Full Logs**

https://gist.github.com/lrrp/3065dff578daa92dacf4bdc78f90c9b5

Any suggestion on how how I can fix this Spring boot error and any best practices to follow in situations such as this?

Comment: Did you find anything, it is almost next year now.